# Flutter - Add item to list of classes

Tags: flutter

If I have

```
Class TestModel {
String property1;
String property2;
bool property3;
}

class PageModel {
List<TestModel> information = [all the data for all 3 properties];
}
```

And I want to add a new item (let's call it newItem) to the List information at the start (index 0), how would I go about doing so? I know that List.add can be used to add an item at the beginning of the List, but I'm not sure how I would do it in this scenario since List information is a List of classes.

Do I need to make newItem a variable of class TestModel before I add it to information? Is there a way to manipulate each property individually (i.e. something like List.add.property1 = "String", List.add.property2 = "String", List.add.property3 = true)

Comment: Yes, you can manipulate each field property just create a new instance of your TestModel. ```TestModel _newTestModel = TestModel(); _newTestModel.property1 = ""; _newTestModel.property2 = null``` and so on then you can ```information.add(_newTestModel);```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `constructor` and directly initialize with `property`

code snippet

```
class TestModel {
  String property1;
  String property2;
  bool property3;

  TestModel({this.property1, this.property2, this.property3});
}

class PageModel {
  List<TestModel> information = [
    TestModel(property1: "1", property2: "2", property3: false),
    TestModel(property1: "3", property2: "4", property3: true)
  ];
}
```

output

```
I/flutter ( 7558):  1 2 false
I/flutter ( 7558):  3 4 true
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestModel {
  String property1;
  String property2;
  bool property3;

  TestModel({this.property1, this.property2, this.property3});
}

class PageModel {
  List<TestModel> information = [
    TestModel(property1: "1", property2: "2", property3: false),
    TestModel(property1: "3", property2: "4", property3: true)
  ];
}

void main() {
  PageModel().information.forEach((element) => print(
      " ${element.property1} ${element.property2} ${element.property3.toString()}"));
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```